# R programming: RODBC and dataframe

Tags: r, rodbc, rjdbc

Having trouble understanding how to pass a dataframe's column value to the query?  The query works fine if I pass the value directly.

The values are stored in df$number.  The tables names are changed for sharing purposes:

```
dataframe <- sqlQuery(connection, "
+ SELECT
+ dimension1,
+ FROM
+ table1,
+ WHERE
+ dimension1 = df$number ")
```

I get the error [1] "42S22 904 [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-00904: \"df$number\": invalid identifier\n"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [gsubfn package](http://gsubfn.googlecode.com) can perform quasi-perl-style string interpolation. Preface any function with `fn$` to turn it on for that function's arguments:

```
library(gsubfn)

num <- 3
dataframe <- fn$sqlQuery(connection, 
         "SELECT dimension1 FROM table1 WHERE dimension1 = $num ")
```

Alternately use `paste` or `sprintf` to construct the string:

```
sql <- paste("SELECT dimension1 FROM table1 WHERE dimension1 =", num)
sqlQuery(connection, sql)
```

or

```
sql <- sprintf("SELECT dimension1 FROM table1 WHERE dimension1 = %d", num)
sqlQuery(connection, sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dataframe <- sqlQuery(connection, paste("
+ SELECT
+ dimension1,
+ FROM
+ table1,
+ WHERE
+ dimension1 =",  df$number))
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement is a string, so it cannot access your dataframe's value. To construct a string which uses the value use:

```
sql.base<-"SELECT dimension1 FROM table1 WHERE dimension1 = "
sql.completed<-paste0(sql.base,df$number)
sqlQuery(connection, sql.completed)
```

If you're looking to do a parameterized SQL query i.e. you have a number of rows in `df`, you can either collapse the field values with a comma seperator and put them in side brackets within a SQL `IN` query. Alternatively you can use the package `RODBCext` which will allow to do it like

```
sqlExecute(connection, "SELECT dimension1 FROM table1 WHERE dimension1 = ?", df$number, fetch = TRUE)
```

For more info on RODBCext and this type of SQL, check out [their vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html)

Comment: Parameterized is exactly what was needed!  RODBCext is exactly what was needed.